# Actualizar un JTable automáticamente en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: java

**Como puedo actualizar mi JTable cuando se esta ejecutando sin la necesidad de hacerlo por medio de un botón?**

Cargo la tabla de la siguiente manera.

```
private void cargarTabla() {
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerClientes = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_clientes()");
            ResultSet rs = obtenerClientes.executeQuery();
            //Obtiene información sobre los tipos y las propiedades de las columnas de un ResultSet.
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            String Titulo[] = {"Nro", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Domicilio", "Teléfono", "Facebook", "Localidad"};
            //Creamos un arreglo y le pasamos rsmd, con getColumnCount() optenemos las cantidades de columnas de la BD.
            Object[] fila = new Object[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
            DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, Titulo);
            while (rs.next()) {
                fila[0] = rs.getInt("Nro"); //Lo que hay entre comillas son los campos de la base de datos.
                fila[1] = rs.getString("Nombre");
                fila[2] = rs.getString("Apellido");
                fila[3] = rs.getString("Domicilio");
                fila[4] = rs.getString("Telefono");
                fila[5] = rs.getString("Facebook");
                fila[6] = rs.getString("Localidad");
                modelo.addRow(fila); // Añade una fila al final del modelo de la tabla
            }
            jTableCliente.setModel(modelo);
            ContarFilas();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar obtener los cliente:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Dentro del evento del botón **Agregar Cliente** llamo a mi JFrame, lleno los campos y luego guardo, llamo al método **cargarTabla()** pero no me actualiza los registros.

```
private void btnAgregarClienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        AgregarClientes agregarClientes = new AgregarClientes();
        agregarClientes.setVisible(true);
        cargarTabla();
        ocultarColumnas();
    }
```

Existe alguna forma de realizarlo? Agradecería su ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

prueba insertar este fragmento de codigo luego de llenar tu tabla en el metodo cargarTabla()

```
modelo.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Este metodo invocara a todos los listener cuando el contenido de la tabla cambie

Espero te sirva
Saludos.

Comment: No, no me a resultado en mi caso, lo e probado.

Answer (score 0):

saludos estoy dando mis primeros pasos en Java y me tope con ese mismo problema una forma de solucionar ese problema.

table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
se le pasa un DefaultTableModel vacio luego se manda a llamar al metodo para llenar la tabla ejemplo.

```
String consulta="Select * from tabla";
table.setModel(consultarDatos(consulta));

public TableModel consultarDatos(String consulta) {
        DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel();
        private Connection conexion;
        private Statement st;
        private ResultSet rs;
        try {
            Class.forName(.....);
            conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(.....);
            st=this.conexion.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery(consulta);
            nombreColumnas(); //metodo para extraer los nombre columna
            datosRegistros();//metodo para extraer datos devueltos
            dtm.setDataVector(.........);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al tratar de cargar los datos");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return dtm;
    }
```

el problema de hacerlo de esta manera es la carga de trabajo que se le da a la BD imagina una tabla con mil registros y cada vez que estas ingresando un nuevo registro debe de volver a cargar los mil registros..

espero te sirva si tienes algun problema avisame y con gusto te puedo ayudar en lo que pueda.

Answer (score -3):

```
usa public void cargarTabla()
```

o llama al metodos asi `this,cargarTabla();`

Comment: Hola jesus garcia, aunque esta respuesta podría servir para guiar  a una solución a la pregunta, ha  sido reportada como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y  contenido. Por favor edítala para añadir algo más de información: ¿dónde  iría  ese código?  ¿qué  es lo que hace? ¿cómo  resolvería el 
 problema? Lee  [answer] y  completa  el [tour] para más información.